# how to set the power button behaviour to turn off the display in linux?

Tags: linux, fedora

I am using Linux Fedora 33,Gnome
I want to set the powerbutton behaviour to turn off the display.
I looked up settings>power>powerbuttonbehaviour but it can set the behaviour to only to on of the following
1)suspend
2)Do nothing
3)poweroff